# Create Jar with Resource Files Separate

Tags: java, compilation, resources

I'm working in IntelliJ and am currently working on a Java program that I expect to need to both distribute and update. It has about 100MB of images that it needs to access, but the images won't need to change between versions. Whenever I compile the project as a jar though, it compiles all of the resource files as well and gives me about a 100MB jar. I have been trying to find a way to make a small Jar file that I send out as a replacement and simply send out the resources only once. However, whenever I try to do this I keep getting null exceptions for loading in the resources.

Thank you

Comment: A multi-module maven project?

Comment: I haven't tried one, I'm not familiar with what they are

Comment: You need to move the images out of this jar. Can you put them next to the jar in the file system instead?